# How do I render TH for individual rows of a table?

Tags: forms

In the example below, how do I make `a1` and `a2` into `<th>` instead of `<td>`?  I want an html table like:

```html
<table data-drupal-selector="edit-test" id="edit-test" class="responsive-enabled table" data-striping="1" data-once="tableresponsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th>a1</th>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th>a2</th>
      <td>b2</td>
      <td>c2</td>
      <td>d2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For a basic table, I can code:

```php
   $form['test'] = [
     '#type' => 'table',
     '#header' => ['a','b','c','d'],
     '#rows' => [
       ['a1','b1','c1','d1'],
       ['a2','b2','c2','d2'],
     ],
   ];
```

and it will render the html as follows with `<td>` for each body cell including `a1` and `a2`:

```html
<table data-drupal-selector="edit-test" id="edit-test" class="responsive-enabled table" data-striping="1" data-once="tableresponsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
      <td>d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
      <td>c2</td>
      <td>d2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```